# How to use ArcGIS FeatureToLine with Managed Assembly

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, .net, arcgis-10.4

I am writing an ArcMap Add-In to combine multiple shapefiles and then run some custom python scripts on the resulting shapefile. However I cannot seem to get the Geoprocessor working to run the FeatureToLine tool.  I am using the ArcGIS SDK 10.4 for .NET.

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

        try
        {
            FeatureToLine FTLTool = new FeatureToLine();

            List<string> inputs = new List<string>();

            string[] ins = new string[] { @"D:\\Code projects\\Network-WZRD\\Network Wzrd\\Data\\Centerlines\\Roadway\\Delaware.shp", 
                @"D:\\Code projects\\Network-WZRD\\Network Wzrd\\Data\\Centerlines\\Trails\\Trails.shp" };

            FTLTool.in_features = ins;
            FTLTool.out_feature_class = @"D:\\Code projects\\Network-WZRD\\Network Wzrd\\atestout.shp";
            ITrackCancel pTrackCancel = new CancelTracker();
            pTrackCancel.CancelOnKeyPress = true;

            gp.Execute(FTLTool, pTrackCancel);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\nAn error occured while attempting to merge shapefiles.\n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }//button5_Click -- Final Load
```

I know I am incorrectly inputing my shapefiles.  But I couldn't find any examples of tools that used multiple inputs in the In_Feature field. I get a general error when it gets to execute the tool

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
```

The questions I have are: How can I input multiple shapefiles into the tool? Does the output need to be an existing shapefile object within the code, or can it just be a path to where I would like the resulting shapefile to be put?

EDIT: 
I tried Hornbydd's suggestion, and used the exact example in the sample code and got the same error code.

```
    public void ExampleGPUsingMultipleInputs()
    {

        // Initialize the geoprocessor.
        Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();

        // Initialize the Union tool.
        Union uniontool = new Union();

        // List all feature classes in the workspace.
        GP.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", @"D:\Code projects\Network-WZRD\Network Wzrd\Data\Centerlines\Trail");
        IGpEnumList fcColl = GP.ListFeatureClasses("*", "", "");

        // Create a StringBuilder object and add the feature classes as a semicolon-delimited list.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string inputfeatures = fcColl.Next();

        while (inputfeatures != "")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(inputfeatures);
            sb.AppendFormat("{0};", inputfeatures);
            inputfeatures = fcColl.Next();
        }

        // Execute the Union tool with multiple inputs creating landuse.shp.
        uniontool.in_features = sb.ToString();
        uniontool.out_feature_class = "landuse.shp";
        GP.Execute(uniontool, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the error is related to how you set your input features. Have a look at [How to use multiple inputs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003m8000000), it gives examples in c# and vb.

Comment: I used the code from the example you gave (I just changed the directories to ones populated with 2 shapefiles) and got the same result: Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.dll

Comment: Solved it.  the union tool doesnt accept shape files with polyLines.  But the feature to line does and it worked! Using a semicolon delineated list for the inputs like: 
       FTLTool.in_features = @"D:\Code projects\Trail\Trails.shp;D:\Code projects\Trail\Trails2.shp;";